# When a button is pressed a div field is visible

Tags: html, css

I have a button in a div container for a scroll box with some profile info, and my goal is when you press the button the div appears (display: initial;), and when you press it again it disappears (display: none;)  Any ideas?

Html:

```
<div>
    <div class="scrollbar">
        <input type="button" class="profile_info">Profile Picture
        <div class="image_change">This is Blue</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
div.scrollbar {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 250px;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 600px;
    padding: 22px;
    margin: 15px;
    position: relative;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

.profile_info {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: Black;
    cursor: pointer;
}

input.profile_info:focus {
    color: Red;
}

input.profile_info:focus ~ .image_change {
    display: block;
}

.image_change {
    display: none;
    position: relative;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: Blue;
}
```

It sort of works if the "image_change" div is in the "scrollbar" div, but if you click away then it disappears.

Thanks!

Comment: Next time, in order for us to help you better, please update your question so that it shows your relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Let us know [what you have tried so far](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) and what didn't work. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since selecting a parent element with CSS is not possible obviously its also not possible to select it's adjacent one....i would suggest the following approach using `javascipt` :

```js
var image = document.getElementsByClassName('image_change')[0]
var input = document.querySelector('input')

input.addEventListener('click',function(e){
   if(image.style.display == '') {
    image.style.display = 'block'
   } else {
    image.style.display = ''
   }
})
```

```css
div.scrollbar {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 250px;
    height: auto;
    max-height: 600px;
    padding: 22px;
    margin: 15px;
    position: relative;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

.profile_info {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: Black;
    cursor: pointer;
}

input.profile_info:checked {
    color: Red;
}


.image_change {
    position: relative;
    display : none;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color: Blue;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="scrollbar">
        <input type="checkbox" class="profile_info">Profile Picture
        
    </div>
    <div class="image_change">
        This is a Blue div
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @TylerPetrov no problem :) if you think it's a correct answer consider validating it